# Web-based server management control panel for RasPi B, lighter than webmin

Tags: web-apps

[Webmin](https://webmin.com/) is too heavy for my old RasPi B. Does anyone know of a similar HTML-based sysadmin tool that's be less resource-hungry? Preferably Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/).

THere are not that many options as Webmin has. And some plugins you might have to build yourself (good luck). It may run on best on Redhat based Linuxes, not Debian based systems. Not sure if it will run on an old Raspi B.

However the basic installation will give you a teminal in the browser which is worth a lot.

Comment: Thanks, worth a look :-)